# How to return values of an asynchronous method call in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am using node js
My code flow is as follows

```
function foo (){
//this returns a value
}
// function foo is an asynchronous call
```

since foo is an asynchronous method, i will not be able to access the return value like

```
var return_value = foo ();
console.log(return_value);
```

this would log as "undefined" in the console, since the asynchrnous call has not yet returned a value

so how should i get that value returned via an asynchronous call to be used in other areas of synchronous code flow?

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use a callback:

```
function foo (callback) {
  callback(return_value);
}

foo(function (return_value) {
  console.log(return_value);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/v3qcy/)